# jQuery plugin using Backbone.js and require.js - How do I pass the "this" variable to a dependency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I need some help.
I am fairly new to *require.js* and I hit a snag. I am creating a jquery plugin that uses the *require.js* architecture.

Once the setupSchedule plugin has been called, it passes on the "this" variable of the element that has called it. jQuery 101. My dependency **ScheduleView** needs this "this" variable and the settings variable. I cannot come up with anything clever on how I can feed these variables to it.

What is the require.js way of doing this?

Thank you!!

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'libs/myFunctions/schedule/views/ScheduleView'
], function($, _, Backbone, ScheduleView){

    return $.fn.setupSchedule = function( options ) {

        // Settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            startTime   : 7,
            endTime     : 9,
            cellHeight  : 30,
            onsubmit    : function () {}
        }, options );

        var _this = this;

        new ScheduleView;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initiate like below.

```
new ScheduleView({element: this, settings: settings});
```

And access like below in your `ScheduleView`

```
 this.options.element //to get the element which called that plugin.
 this.options.settings //to get settings of that plugin.
```